# Detecting width of Different Desktop Monitor for Responsive Design

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

Hi I am trying to learn how to write CSS media queries and I am almost lost at very beginning ! As you know there are several sizes of monitors out side like

11",
13", 
14", 
15", 
17", 
22", 
24", 
27"

now my question is how I can find the standard width for all of these monitors and how I can detect the width of the them in a few media queries which can cover all sizes from biggest to smallest. I already find this link "[Media Queries for Standard Devices](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)" by CSS-TRICKS, for standard potable mobile devices but need some thing for desktop monitors as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Media queries are based on pixel dimensions, not inches.

You won't be able to target all dimensions of all devices, there are just too many coming onto the market everyday.

Take a Device Agnostic Responsive Layout approach for targeting multiple dimensions and devices.

Comment: Thanks Lokase, so for an a situation like above what would be the best options?

Comment: Start here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/22/device-agnostic-approach-to-responsive-web-design/.  Basically the idea is to set a range of media queries then have a fluid layout that expands or contracts to the specific media query range.

Answer (score 2):

As Lokase said, media queries are based on pixel dimensions.

A specific monitor size doesn't means specific pixel dimension since you can use 1024x768, 1920x1200, ... all with a 22" screen size for example.

If you're interested in responsive design (media queries are largely used for this), i would sugest you to look for "breaking point" and not "screen size" :)